# Control the stop/start of a conveyor belt using a sensor (proximity or photoelectric)

Tags: power-supply, dc-motor

I am not too familiar with electric systems so sorry if this is a dumb question. I was wondering if there was a method to stop a conveyor belt using a DC moor with 115 vac 1 phase input using a proximity or photoelectric sensor. Once the sensor detects an object, power to the conveyor is cut.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why do you say DC motor, when it is powered by AC?

Comment: There is. Return to us after picking a photosensor and we can tell you how to use it since they are not all the same.

Comment: The part about the motor is obscure: is it a DC motor, or a 115 VAC one? But, anyway, the answer is YES, **it is possible** for a skilled person to project and build a circuit to stop the conveyor belt, in such way that, _"once the sensor detects an object, the power to the conveyor is cut"._

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdx2ej.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Circuit for AC powered motor.*

This circuit switches the mains power for your motor.

- When the sensor is triggered RLY1 is energised.
- The motor is powered from an NC (normally closed contact). When this opens the motor stops.

The sensor and relay coil need to be rated for the voltage of your mains supply. The relay contacts need to be motor rated and go for a rating several times that of your motor's run current to be sure that it can handle the starting current.

Fuses are not optional (although your motor may have one already).

Comment: You probably want to add a flyback diode into that for the OP. And also mentioned that this is for a line powered photo sensor, which many will not be, or that the photosensor block is a generic circuit yet to be determined since the OP has provided no specific sensor.

Comment: Um, a flyback diode on the output of an AC sensor? I covered the sensor voltage in the answer.

Comment: Or rather a snubber instead of a diode, since it's AC. Kinda depends on the photosensor really which is as of yet, unspecified.

Comment: Most will have internal protection.